# Construct a function with following properties.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f :[0,1] \to  \mathbb{R}$ , such that : $\forall x \in [0,1]$ there is exists finit $f'(x)$, but set of points of discontinuity of first derivative has positive measure.

It's strange, because of the fact that points of discontinuity of first derivative has no limit (left or right) at all. Have no idea how to step it.

Comment: what does there exists bounded f'(x) mean??

Comment: @mathworker21 sorry for my English

Comment: I'm just confused because if $f'(x)$ exists, then $f$ is continuous at $x$

Comment: @mathworker21 it's points of discontinuity of derivative

Comment: ohhhh, you should clarify that

Comment: Not sure, but could this be related to pathological functions... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_(mathematics) ... Just a thought as not enough time to think about this properly.

Comment: How about taking the standard example of a function whose derivative is not continuous at a point, modifying it so the derivative is not continuous at $0$ and $1$,, then by constructing an appropriate sum, obtain a function whose derivative is discontinuous on a fat cantor set?

Comment: @Driver8 what kind of sum?

Comment: My idea is as follows: Take intervals $I_{n,k}\subset I$ in a fat Cantor set and sppose you've constructed functions $f_{n,k}$ bounded by $1$ such that each $f_{n,k}$ has discontinuos derivative at each endpoint of $I_{n,k}.$ Relabel the $f's$ so that they are arranged in a sequence which we may as well just call $f_n.$ Then take $\sum 2^{-n}f_n.$ I don't know if this will work, it's just an idea---